# How can I display an embedded view's toolbar?

Tags: ios, ios7, toolbar

I have a tableview which is embedded in a standard view controller. The tableview has a toolbar, which I want to display.

At the moment, the toolbar remains undisplayed.

This I have tried:

- Setting the toolbar to show in the embedded table view (code+storyboard).
- Setting the toolbar to show in the parent view controller (code + storyboard).
- Setting to toolbar to not show in the view controller, but to show in the embedded table (code + storyboard).

The toolbar is present (and displays correctly) if I access the table directly and not via the embedded view. Does the action of embedding the view remove the toolbar?

How can I display the tableviews toolbar in the embedded view?

EDIT: New Code

ParentViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "childTable.h"

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UpdateParentProtocol>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *emailButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *buttonEnabled;
@property (weak, nonatomic) ChildTable *childTableVC;

@end
```

---

```
parentViewController.m

#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ParentViewController

@synthesize emailButton;
@synthesize buttonEnabled;
@synthesize childTableVC;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
        [super viewDidLoad];

 [self.childTableVC setDelegate:self];

}


-(void) isButtonEnabled:(NSString *)enabledX {

    NSLog(@"isButtonEnabled");

    enabledX = buttonEnabled;

if ([buttonEnabled isEqualToString:@"FALSE"])
{

    emailButton.enabled = FALSE;


}
else
{
    emailButton.enabled = TRUE;

}
}
```

---

```
childTable.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@protocol UpdateParentProtocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void) isButtonEnabled: (NSString *) enabledX;

@end

@interface childTable: UITableViewController {

    id <UpdateParentProtocol> delegate;

}

//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *emailButton;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *enabledX;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id <UpdateParentProtocol> delegate;
```

---

```
childTable.m

 -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"TableEditingEnded");

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

self.myArray = [defaults mutableArrayValueForKey:@"favourite_views_key"];

if (myArray == 0) {

    enabledX = @"FALSE";
    NSLog(@"PASSEDFALSE");

    [[self delegate] isButtonEnabled:enabledX];  }

else {

    enabledX = @"TRUE";
    NSLog(@"PASSEDTRUE");

    [[self delegate] isButtonEnabled:enabledX];  }

}
```

When I run the code, I get an NSLog print out of TableEditingEnded and PASSEDTRUE, but no isButtonEnabled. This suggests to me that -(void) isButtonEnabled:(NSString *)enabledX  is not being called. Could you suggests as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to communicate from child to parent view controller using a protocol

```
@protocol UpdateParentProtocol <NSObject>

-(void)doSomething1;
-(void)doSomething2;

@end

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController<UpdateParentProtocol>

@end

@implementation ParentViewController
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    TableViewController *tableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    tableViewController.delegate = self;
}

-(void)doSomething1
{
    NSLog(@"doSomething1");
}

-(void)doSomething2
{
    NSLog(@"doSomething2");
}

@end
----

#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController

@property(strong, nonatomic) id<UpdateParentProtocol> delegate;

@end

@implementation TableViewController


-(void)updateParentWithData
{
    if( [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doSomething1)])
    {
        [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(doSomething1)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Jonah but I easily implemented a toolbar on my table view. The toolbar on the table view has a button tied to the number of items in the table, when the number reaches zero, the button becomes unavailable (to avoid a crash). I did originally try to put the toolbar in the parent view controller, but found passing data from the child to the parent every time the count reaches zero annoyingly complex. Perhaps if you can't offer any advice on displaying the toolbar in the child view, you could give some information as to how to pass the data back from the child to the parent?

Comment: You can pass data between view controllers in a number of different ways. 1) You can create the toolbar in your parent view controller and then pass a reference to your table view controller by means of a property 2) You can use blocks 3) You can use delegates.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; my current data transfer method (for passing data forward) uses 1, but I use segues to actually perform the data transfer process. As there is no segue activated when the user edits the child table (therefore meaning the button should be greyed out) how would you recommend I actually pass the data to the parent in this case?

Comment: Thanks for your input, looks like the protocol method is the way to go for me. I've had a solid go at trying to implement it using your instructions (and some extra reading) but I'm getting stumped at why its not calling the method I've put in the parentviewcontroller, would you have a look at the code I just posted? (If you want I'll move this to a new question and mark both as correct if you can help me out).

Comment: Where is the childTableVC property being set? Put a breakpoint in your ParentViewController viewDidLoad and see if childTableVC is nil.

Comment: Hi Jonah, I set a breakpoint as requested and the simulation terminated at [self.childTableVC setDelegate:self]; as expected. Any other ideas?

Comment: Where is the childTableVC property being set? The reason for the breakpoint was to tell if your childTableVC is actually being created somewhere since I don't see it in your code. Are you using a container view and an embed segue?

Comment: I had thought I had set it in the parent.h @property (weak, nonatomic) ChildTable *childTableVC; here. That said I'm still learning a huge amount so please correct me if I'm wrong. Yeah your spot on, I am using a container view. The parent has a container view and the child is the table embedded in that container.

Comment: You need to implement prepareForSegue like i did in my ParentViewController, but instead do self.childTableVC = segue.destinationViewController. Also, make childTableVC a strong property instead of a weak one.

Comment: Those two changes sorted it Jonah, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. This problem had been driving me crazy for a while, so honestly; thank you. You don't have to, but as one last thing do you think you could quickly explain to me why the prepare for segue was the key?

Comment: Glad I could help out. You need the prepareForSegue as there is no other way to get the reference to what is embedded in the container view. Another way to handle it would be to use view controller containment (which is essentially what this is). But then you have to do all of the work to set up the relationship in code rather than letting IB do the heavy lifting for you.